# Finding the limit of repeated definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

So here is the corrected problem. I'm just not sure of the procedure for solving a problem like this.

$$Y=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\frac{y_1^{295}+y_2^{295}+y_3^{295}+\cdots+y_n^{295}}{y_1^{1080}+y_2^{1080}+y_3^{1080}+\cdots+y_n^{1080}}dy_1dy_2dy_3dy_4\dots dy_n$$

I need to find $Y^2$ in a fractional form. How do I solve these many integrals without knowing how many there are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. $\operatorname{Uniform}([0,1])$ random variables and write

$$ Z_n := \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k^{295}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k^{1080}}. $$

Then the limit in question can be recast as

$$ Y = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[ Z_n \right]. $$

By the Strong Law of Large Numbers, we know that

$$ Z_n
= \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k^{295}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k^{1080}}
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y_1^{295}]}{\mathbb{E}[Y_1^{1080}]}
= \frac{1081}{296} \qquad \mathbb{P}\text{-almost surely}. $$

This suggests that

$$Y = \frac{1081}{296}, \tag{*}$$

provided we can interchange the order of limit and expectation. This indeed turns out to be the case, but this is by no means a trivial question. So we spend the rest of this answer justifying this.

---

By the Jensen's inequality $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k \leq \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} |x_k|^p \right)^{1/p}$ which holds for any $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p \geq 1$, we get

$$ Z_n
\leq \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k^{295} \right)^{-157/59}
\leq \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k^2 \right)^{-785/2}. $$

Also, if $B^{n}(r)$ denotes the $r$-ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for $y > 0$,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P} \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_{k}^{2} \leq y \right)
&\leq \operatorname{Volume}\left( B^{n}(\sqrt{ny}) \cap [0, \infty)^{n} \right) \\
&= \frac{(\pi n y)^{n/2}}{2^n \Gamma(1+\frac{n}{2})}
\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \left( \frac{\pi y}{2e} \right)^{n/2},
\end{align*}

where we utilized the quantitative form of the Stirling's formula $\Gamma(1+s) \geq \sqrt{2\pi s} (s/e)^s $ for $s \geq 1$ in the last step. So, if $p > 1$ and $n > 2q$ for $q := 785p/2$, then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ Z_n^p \right]
&\leq \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_k^2 \right)^{-q} \right] \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{q}{y^{q+1}} \mathbb{P} \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} Y_{k}^{2} \leq y \right) \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{1} \frac{q}{y^{q+1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \left( \frac{\pi y}{2e} \right)^{n/2} \, \mathrm{d}y + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{q}{y^{q+1}} \, \mathrm{d}y,
\end{align*}

which can be shown to be bounded uniformly in $n > 2q$. This shows that $(Z_n)_{n > 2q}$ is uniformly integrable. Since $Z_n \to 1081/296$ in probability, these altogether implies that $Z_n \to 1081/296$ in $L^1$, proving $\text{(*)}$ as required.

Comment: Where does the 157/59 come from in the inequality?

Comment: @JamesR, That comes from bounding the denominator by $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_k^{1080}\geq\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_k^{295}\right)^{1080/295} $$ using the Jensen's Inequality. This gives $$ Z_n \leq \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_k^{295}}{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_k^{295}\right)^{1080/295}}, $$ and simplifying this gives the first part of the inequality.

Comment: OH that makes much more sense. Thank you so much. :)